# I was creating a virtual mouse and I keep getting this error. I have tried with autopy and with pyautogui but in both cases it gives me same error

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, mediapipe, autopy

This is the error I'm getting right now and I just can't figure out what the problem is.

```
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\AIproject\virMouse.py", line 18, in <module>
    lmList, bbox = detector.findPosition(img)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my code for the virtual mouse program that I have written so far.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import HTmodule as htm
import autopy

wCam, hCam = 640, 480

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, wCam)
cap.set(4, hCam)
pTime = 0
detector = htm.handDetector(maxHands=1)

while True:
     success, img = cap.read()
     img = detector.findHands(img)
     lmList, bbox = detector.findPosition(img)


     cTime = time.time()
     fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
     pTime = cTime
     cv2.putText(img, f'FPS:{(int(fps))}', (5, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 1, (204, 0, 0), 2)
     cv2.imshow("Image", img)
     cv2.waitKey(1)
```

And here is the code for the hand tracking module that I wrote.

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time

class handDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2,modelC=1, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.modelC = modelC
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon

        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, self.modelC, self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

    def findHands(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
        # print(result.multi_hand_landmarks)

        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLms in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms, self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)

        return img
    def findPosition(self, img, handNo=0, draw=True):
        lmList=[]
        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            myHand = self.results.multi_hand_landmarks[handNo]
            for id, lm in enumerate(myHand.landmark):
                # print(id,lm)
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                # print(id, cx, cy)
                lmList.append([id, cx, cy])
                # if id == 0:
                if draw:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 3, (229, 25, 66), cv2.FILLED)
        return lmList


def main():
    pTime = 0
    cTime = 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    detector = handDetector()
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        img = detector.findHands(img)
        lmList = detector.findPosition(img, draw=False)
        # print(lmList) # PRINTS THE LIST OF LANDMARKS
        if len(lmList) != 0:
            print(lmList[4])
        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
        pTime = cTime

        cv2.putText(img, f'FPS:{(int(fps))}', (5, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 1, (9, 9, 255), 1)

        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I don't think it has anything to do with autopy I think it has something to do with findPosition() function but I can't figure out what it is. I just started studying computer vision with python and decided to make this project for my practice but this error I can't seem to debug. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou very much.

Comment: Your `findPosition()` method returns a list of arbitrary length, depending on what was detected in the image.  Assigning that return value to two variables will only work when the list contains exactly two elements.

Comment: Yea I got it. Returned bbox along with lmlist in the HTmodule file and it worked. Thanks:)